# TFS to VSO migration error - The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

Trying to migrate only source and history from TFS to VSO. Error failed with following error. I could not find any help online, not sure what key or how to handle. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

OpsHubTFSService.log

```
$/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PIOLEDB_E_Setup/resource.h. Items 1
2015-12-10 08:53:32,930 [7] DEBUG Getting items for server item [137756] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PIOLEDB_P_Setup/resource.h.
2015-12-10 08:53:33,052 [7] DEBUG Retrived items for server item [137756] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PIOLEDB_P_Setup/resource.h. Items 1
2015-12-10 08:53:33,052 [7] DEBUG Getting items for server item [137789] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PointBuilderSetup/PointBuilderSetup.cpp.
2015-12-10 08:53:33,168 [7] DEBUG Retrived items for server item [137789] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PointBuilderSetup/PointBuilderSetup.cpp. Items 1
2015-12-10 08:53:33,168 [7] DEBUG Getting items for server item [137763] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PointBuilderSetup/PointBuilderSetup.dsp.
2015-12-10 08:53:33,283 [7] DEBUG Retrived items for server item [137763] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PointBuilderSetup/PointBuilderSetup.dsp. Items 1
2015-12-10 08:53:33,283 [7] DEBUG Getting items for server item [137762] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PointBuilderSetup/PointBuilderSetup.dsw.
2015-12-10 08:53:33,403 [7] DEBUG Retrived items for server item [137762] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PointBuilderSetup/PointBuilderSetup.dsw. Items 1
2015-12-10 08:53:33,403 [7] DEBUG Getting items for server item [137762] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PointBuilderSetup/PointBuilderSetup.h.
2015-12-10 08:53:33,586 [7] DEBUG Retrived items for server item [137762] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PointBuilderSetup/PointBuilderSetup.h. Items 1
2015-12-10 08:53:33,586 [7] DEBUG Getting items for server item [137762] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PointBuilderSetup/PointBuilderSetup.plg.
2015-12-10 08:53:33,715 [7] DEBUG Retrived items for server item [137762] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/PointBuilderSetup/PointBuilderSetup.plg. Items 1
2015-12-10 08:53:33,715 [7] DEBUG Getting items for server item [137749] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/resource.h.
2015-12-10 08:53:33,832 [7] DEBUG Retrived items for server item [137749] $/Setup/Wrapper/Source/resource.h. Items 12
2015-12-10 08:53:33,834 [7] ERROR Error : The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Service.Adapters.TFSVCAdapter.getLabelItemsHistory(String labelName, String scope, List`1 projects) in f:\Ashish Docs\Checkouts\09_06_2014\OVSMU-V1.0-Rels1\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSVersionControl\AdapterComponents\TFSVCAdapter.cs:line 500
   at com.opshub.tfs.test.TFSWebService.getLabelItemsHistory(String authToken, LocalWorkspaceInfo workspaceInfo, String labelName, String scope, List`1 projectNames) in f:\Ashish Docs\Checkouts\09_06_2014\OVSMU-V1.0-Rels1\OpsHubV2\TFSWCFServiceSource\Service\Service\TFSWebService.cs:line 658
   at SyncInvokegetLabelItemsHistory(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

2015-12-10 08:53:33,976 [7] DEBUG Logout successful for token 09712598-070d-4707-8052-f568f45d9917
2015-12-10 08:53:40,287 [7] DEBUG Connecting to the team foundation server instance http://tfs:8080/tfs/
2015-12-10 08:53:40,411 [7] DEBUG Login successful for token fe6bc80f-07e0-4cd3-bfbd-d0bb67b9bfe3
2015-12-10 08:53:41,224 [7] DEBUG Fetching projects of the collection.
2015-12-10 08:53:41,367 [7] DEBUG Getting maximum Commit ID
2015-12-10 08:53:41,554 [7] DEBUG Retrived the maximum Commit ID
2015-12-10 08:53:41,558 [7] DEBUG Getting all labels history for projects :Setup, from 08/02/2010 22:47:59 and 01/01/0001 00:00:00
```

Comment: The free opshub migration tool no longer functions as advertised. I would recommend switching to TFS Integration Tools.

Comment: Can you share the opshub logs? It locates at opshub installation folder.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT added log details in the original question.

Comment: Hi, can you please share details of the OpsHubTFSService.log? That's if the source of detailed information of this issue.

Comment: @OpshubInc. added error details from the tfsservice.log

Comment: Looks like an issue on our end. Let us verify and get back to you on this.

Comment: Hi, can you share the version of the OpsHub tool as well as the logs to ovsmu@opshub.com? We might need more information for this issue.

Comment: Hi, the new version of our tool is out. It handles the fixation of the issue that you were facing. Please try it out (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2)